# Passing ref to directive binding makes `Maximum recursive updates exceeded`

Tags: vue.js, directive, vue-composition-api

I want to create a directive in Vue3 and using composition API. I also want to pass ref to another element as binding to my directive. So I have written the following piece of code:

```js
<template>
    <div class="content" v-context-menu="contextMenuElement">
        <SmartContextMenu ref="contextMenuElement" :items="[]" />
    </div>
</template>
// ...
<script>
//...
const contextMenuElement = ref(null)
//...
</script>
```

Which makes the browser cause this error:

> Maximum recursive updates exceeded

And I have changed the binding of directive this way to fix the error:

```js
<template>
    <div class="content" v-context-menu="() => contextMenuElement">
        <SmartContextMenu ref="contextMenuElement" :items="[]" />
    </div>
</template>
// ...
<script>
//...
const contextMenuElement = ref(null)
//...
</script>
```

So that in the directive lifecycles I have to use `binding.value()` instead of `binding.value` or even `binding`.
**Is there any better solution for this issue (passing ref (ref()) to directive (binding))?**